# Output json with os.stdout.write and a new line?

Tags: go, go-gin

new to golang here. I wanted to simply output some json to stdout for debug purposes. I think I'm going about this all wrong. Here is what I have:

```
type SomeObject struct {
  Thing1 string
  Thing2 string
  Thing3 otherStruct
}

...

someObject = &SomeObject{
  Thing1: "hello",
  Thing2: "world",
  ...
}
someObjectLogEntry, err := json.Marshal(someObject)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
os.Stdout.Write(someObjectLogEntry)
```

When I run this, it outputs the json as one line, however my service also has a heartbeat going and so the two coincide and output both things in the same line, something like:

```
{/// All that json content }[GIN] 2022/03/16 - 02:07:16 | 200 | 1.16µs | 127.0.0.1 | GET "/heartbeat"
```

What's the correct way to do what I'm doing (simply constructing a json object and outputting it)? If i do `fmt.println` it will then print out the byte code. Thanks!

Comment: You can convert the []byte into a string, like fmt.Println(string(someObjectLogEntry))

Answer (score 0):

You need to output a line feed or newline ([`\n`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals)) after the JSON. The simplest approach is probably using [`fmt.Printf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Printf) e.g. ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GIEx5uN5Cm2))

```
type SomeObject struct {
    Thing1 string
    Thing2 string
}
someObject := &SomeObject{
    Thing1: "hello",
    Thing2: "world",
}
someObjectLogEntry, err := json.Marshal(someObject)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", someObjectLogEntry)
os.Stdout.Write([]byte("something else\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to achieve this while using the `Printf` function from the `fmt` package is by including a newline character `\n` in the format string. You don’t necessarily need to write the data to standard output, because `Printf` does that for you.

Another option is to use the `Println` function from the `fmt` package which formats using the default formats for its operands writes to standard output. It’s necessary to convert your JSON `bytes` to `string` while using `Println`. Note that, spaces are always added between the operands and a newline is appended while using `Println`.

The reason that you see individual byte values while using `fmt.Println` is because a byte slice is printed out as uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice — the byte slice can contain anything at all, not just printable characters. On the other hand, `os.Stdout.Write` writes the byte slice to standard out and your terminal renders them properly because they are printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach is to use json.Encoder to os.Stdout.

json.Encoder already appends a newline to each message written and is more efficient than using fmt with json bytes.

You can re-use the json encoder instead of calling json.Marshal then some type of separate write for each message.

```golang
import (
   "os"
   "encoding/json"
)

type SomeObject struct {
  Thing1 string
  Thing2 string
  Thing3 otherStruct
}

...

encoder := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

someObject = &SomeObject{
  Thing1: "hello",
  Thing2: "world",
  ...
}

if err := encoder.Encode(&someObject); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```